# What does "occurred in the sound" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The below paragraph is from a website I came across recently. Could anyone explain to me what the author means by "occurred in the sound' in the below paragraph?

> Because the birds apparently died of starvation, logic follows that the birds were unable to find appropriate food. For these birds, that would be ocean herring and other fish whose populations are known to be in decline. It’s worth noting that herring numbers in particular have been low since the 1983 Exxon Valdez oil spill, which **occurred in the sound**.

Comment: As Ricky's answer correctly stated, the sound is Prince William Sound.  I would have expected "sound" to be capitalized in this context.

Comment: You are right. It is the name of a place. a noun. I have pasted the exact para from the original article http://inhabitat.com/is-climate-change-causing-alaskan-seabirds-to-starve-to-death/ . The author should've used a capital 'S' for 'sound'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In geography, a sound is a large sea or ocean inlet larger than a bay, deeper than a bight, and wider than a fjord. - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_%28geography%29)

The Exxon Valdez oil spill took place in the Prince William Sound.

[image]

Comment: You might have posted a prior draft - I tidied it up a little for you. Feel free to roll back.